# Falha ao executar o comando "cmake .." no prompt

Tags: cmd, prompt, cmake

Estou estudando detecção de objetos com Python e Dlib e para isso eu preciso compilar a pasta imglab dentro do diretório: "dlib-19.17\tools\imglab" do arquivo dlib-19.7 que eu baixei do site oficial http://dlib.net. Nessa pasta tem um txt README com instruções da instalação e quando chego na parte que devo executar o comando `cmake ..` aparece o seguinte erro no meu prompt:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (PROJECT):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (PROJECT):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/marco/Desktop/PROGRAMA/dlib-19.17/tools/imglab/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/marco/Desktop/PROGRAMA/dlib-19.17/tools/imglab/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

C:\Users\marco\Desktop\PROGRAMA\dlib-19.17\tools\imglab\build>cmake --build . --config Release
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: nmake /nologo
```

**Arquivo CMakeOutput.log**

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.17134 - AMD64
```

**Arquivo CMakeError.log"**

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
```

**Eu tenho o Cmake versão 3.14.3 instalado**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa ter algum Visual Studio instalado, pode até ser o Express ou o Community. (Atenção: redistributable não é compilador).

Além disso você tem que usar o "generator" certo, cada versão de Visual C++ tem um generator diferente. Mas o que é "generator" ? Generator é o valor passado no parâmetro -G na linha de chamada do cmake. Para saber os generators existentes você usa o comando "cmake --help". Um exemplo parcial:

```
...
    The following generators are available on this platform:
  Visual Studio 15 [arch]      = Generates Visual Studio 15 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
...
```

Comment: Deu super certo aqui, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

O Cmake não encontrou o compilador, no seu caso você está tentando compilar em Visual C++, você precisa instalar Visual C++

Comment: Eu tenho o Visual C++ instalado, versões:  2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 e 2017 todas redistributable

Comment: Você precisa instalar Build Tools a redistributable e o runtime do Visual C++

Comment: aqui link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo!!